# Allowing params for a nested attribute with custom devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my rails application I have a User and a Profile where the profile belongs to the user.

I have overridden the normal devise registration controller to avoid asking the user for a password in the sign up form. I am also creating the profile resource as a nested resource in the same form. When I submit the form, the profile resource gets created, although without any of the information from the form.

The params from my form look like the below:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2sFwrzojZOwB0U/TRScuT9x8lInXGyJX/G1WrYiJOBfFwsT79xlZHZnje1kGAgyzxZtVJ6F3PW4YzQTnDUsZwg==", "user"=>{"role"=>"junior", "profile"=>{"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"asldm2"}, "email"=>"aksdm@gmail.com", "language"=>"javascript"}}
```

I can see why this is:

```
Unpermitted parameters: profile
```

My problem is telling Devise to accept profile parameters during the registration.

Following the help here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters I have tried to configure the parameters in my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit([:id, :email, profile_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :role]])
    end
  end
end
```

My user User Model looks like the below. Please note my method to create with an automatically generated password

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  before_validation :generate_password, on: :create
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  def self.create_with_password(params)
    @email = params[:email]
    generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
    @user = self.create!(email: @email, password: generated_password)
    UserNotifier.send_sign_up_email(@user, generated_password).deliver if @user.persisted?
    return @user
  end

  def generate_password
    generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
    self.password = self.password_confirmation = generated_password if !self.password.blank?
  end


  def password_required?
    new_record? ? false : super
  end

end
```

My Profile Model looks like this:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Further, below is my RegistrationController which I am using to call the create method in my user model

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
      logger.debug "Registrations create"
      @user = User.create_with_password(user_params)
      logger.debug "Registrations user created with password"
      @user.build_profile
      @user.update(user_params)
      logger.debug "User: #{@user.inspect}"
      sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to user_url
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit([:id, :email, profile_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :role, :language]])
  end
end
```

My sign up form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: {controller: :registrations, action: :create} do |f| %>
    <ul class="flex-outer">
      <li>
         <label>I am a</label>
      </li>
    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |pf| %>
      <ul class="flex-inner role">
        <li class="role-radio">
          <%= pf.radio_button :role, 'junior' %>
          <label for="user_role_junior">
            <div class="role-div">
              <div class="role-circle">
                <img src="svg/student.svg" alt="student icon">
              </div>
              <div>Junior</div>
            </div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="role-radio">

          <%= pf.radio_button :role, 'employer' %>
          <label for="user_role_employer">
            <div class="role-div">
              <div class="role-circle">
                <img src="svg/employer.svg" alt="employer icon">
              </div>
              <div>Employer</div>
            </div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li>
        <%= pf.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
        <%= pf.text_field :first_name, id: "first-name", placeholder: "Jon" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= pf.label :last_name, "Last Name" %>
        <%= pf.text_field :last_name, id: "last-name", placeholder: "Snow" %>
      </li>
      <li>
      <% end %>
        <%= f.label :email, "Email" %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, id: "email", placeholder: "JSnow@winterfell.com" %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%#f.label :'company-name', "Company name" %>
        <%# f.text_field :'company-name', id: "company-name", placeholder: "Winterfell Ltd" %>
        <!-- <label for="company-name">Company name</label>
        <input type="company-name" id="company-name" placeholder="Winterfell Ltd"> -->
      </li>
      <li>
         <label>I want to receive my test in</label>
      </li>
      // Fields removed for brevity
      <li class="submit-button">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Is anyone able to help me troubleshoot this?

Edit: Updated to include form and routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :user, skip: [:sessions], controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
  as :user do
    delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
    get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
  end
  resource :user, path: 'account' do
     resource :profile, :test
     resources :connections
  end

  get '/how-it-works' => 'home#how-it-works'
  get '/sign-up' => 'home#sign-up'
  get '/user' => 'users#index', as: :user_root

  root 'home#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Rake routes are as below:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
       new_user_password GET    /user/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /user/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /user/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /user/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /user/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /user/cancel(.:format)                  registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /user/sign_up(.:format)                 registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /user/edit(.:format)                    registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /user(.:format)                         registrations#update
                         PUT    /user(.:format)                         registrations#update
                         DELETE /user(.:format)                         registrations#destroy
                         POST   /user(.:format)                         registrations#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /sign_out(.:format)                     devise/sessions#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#create
        new_user_profile GET    /account/profile/new(.:format)          profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /account/profile/edit(.:format)         profiles#edit
            user_profile GET    /account/profile(.:format)              profiles#show
                         PATCH  /account/profile(.:format)              profiles#update
                         PUT    /account/profile(.:format)              profiles#update
                         DELETE /account/profile(.:format)              profiles#destroy
                         POST   /account/profile(.:format)              profiles#create
           new_user_test GET    /account/test/new(.:format)             tests#new
          edit_user_test GET    /account/test/edit(.:format)            tests#edit
               user_test GET    /account/test(.:format)                 tests#show
                         PATCH  /account/test(.:format)                 tests#update
                         PUT    /account/test(.:format)                 tests#update
                         DELETE /account/test(.:format)                 tests#destroy
                         POST   /account/test(.:format)                 tests#create
        user_connections GET    /account/connections(.:format)          connections#index
                         POST   /account/connections(.:format)          connections#create
     new_user_connection GET    /account/connections/new(.:format)      connections#new
    edit_user_connection GET    /account/connections/:id/edit(.:format) connections#edit
         user_connection GET    /account/connections/:id(.:format)      connections#show
                         PATCH  /account/connections/:id(.:format)      connections#update
                         PUT    /account/connections/:id(.:format)      connections#update
                         DELETE /account/connections/:id(.:format)      connections#destroy
                new_user GET    /account/new(.:format)                  users#new
               edit_user GET    /account/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
                    user GET    /account(.:format)                      users#show
                         PATCH  /account(.:format)                      users#update
                         PUT    /account(.:format)                      users#update
                         DELETE /account(.:format)                      users#destroy
                         POST   /account(.:format)                      users#create
            how_it_works GET    /how-it-works(.:format)                 home#how-it-works
                 sign_up GET    /sign-up(.:format)                      home#sign-up
               user_root GET    /user(.:format)                         users#index
                    root GET    /                                       home#index
```

Comment: Can you show us the form code?

Comment: Done @Pavan , thanks for getting back to me

Answer (score 0):

Try by override Devise `Registrations#new` method, add below method in your registrations controller  :

```
  def new
    # Override Devise default behaviour and create a profile as well
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_profile
    respond_with self.resource
  end
```

also make sure you have defined in route:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately that hasn't changed the error message. I have displayed my routes for you above.

Comment: @Powderham : run `rake routes` and update it in your question

Comment: Done @Gagan-Gami.